# String with 1000 digits, find the biggest 5 digits without an array

Tags: java, string, numbers, digits, charat

I know my code can be simpler and more efficient... My code is supposed to grab the biggest set of 5 digits. It works, except it only is grabbing 3 digits, what would i need to modify to change that?

```
public class thousandDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int greatest = 0;
        String num = ("73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                + "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
                + "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
                + "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
                + "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
                + "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
                + "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
                + "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
                + "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
                + "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
                + "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
                + "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
                + "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
                + "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
                + "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
                + "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
                + "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
                + "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
                + "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
                + "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450");

        for (int n = 0; n < num.length() - 5; n++) {
            greatest = ((num.charAt(n)) + (num.charAt(n+1)) + (num.charAt(n+2)) + (num.charAt(n+3))
                    + (num.charAt(n+4)));
            if (greatest > n) {
                n = greatest;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(greatest);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
357
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. There is 3 digit number 963 which is greater than 357.

Comment: I think you mean `num.charAt(n+1)` not `(num.charAt(n)+1)`. Also, you need to multiply the first digit by 10^(6-n) where n=1 to start with for each digit n=1...5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @ElliottFrisch and @dave provides more elegant answer, I tried to modify from your original version and here is my code (I have tested it):

```
public class ThousandDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int greatest = 0;
        String num = ("73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                + "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
                + "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
                + "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
                + "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
                + "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
                + "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
                + "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
                + "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
                + "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
                + "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
                + "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
                + "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
                + "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
                + "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
                + "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
                + "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
                + "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
                + "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
                + "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450");

        int max = -1;
        for (int n = 0; n < num.length() - 4; n++) {
            greatest = ((num.charAt(n) - '0') * 10000 + (num.charAt(n + 1) - '0') * 1000
                    + (num.charAt(n + 2) - '0') * 100 + (num.charAt(n + 3) - '0') * 10 + (num.charAt(n + 4) - '0'));
            if (max < greatest) {
                max = greatest;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you multiply the num.charAt by 1000 for the first 2 then 100 for the third one and then only 10 for the last one?

Comment: @Frank Because from your question I believe we are finding the largest 5 digits (e.g., 99890), not the sum of the 5 digits (e.g., 9 + 9 + 8 + 9 + 0 = 35). Therefore, we need to reconstruct the number by regarding the first 9 as 90000 (that's why multiply it by 10000), the second 9 as 9000, and so on. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use [`String.substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) to iterate all possible 5 character substrings, and then you might use [`Math.max(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-) to update `greatest`. Something like

```
int greatest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < num.length() - 4; i++) {
    // int value = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(i, i + 5));
    int value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num.charAt(i))
                + num.charAt(1 + i) + num.charAt(2 + i) + num.charAt(3 + i)
                + num.charAt(4 + i));
    greatest = Math.max(greatest, value);
}
System.out.println(greatest);
```

I get `99890`.

Comment: Im not supposed to use subString yet in this program, i appreciate the help though

Comment: @Frank Edited. Next time please list all of your restrictions to get better help faster (you said only no arrays).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to add 5 consecutive characters to get sum, and store starting index of highest sum.

But you should be using [Character.getNumricValue(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) to convert (num.charAt(n)) to numeric value and then add.

```
greatest  = Character.getNumericValue((num.charAt(n)) + Character.getNumericValue((num.charAt(n+1)) + Character.getNumericValue((num.charAt(n+2)) + 
Character.getNumericValue((num.charAt(n+3)) + 
Character.getNumericValue((num.charAt(n+4));
```

You need a valirable to store old value to compare and index

```
if(greatest > oldGreatest) {
    index = n;
}
```

Then finally print using index out side loop:

```
System.out.print((num.charAt(index)) + (num.charAt(index+1) + (num.charAt(index +2)) + (num.charAt(index +3)) + (num.charAt(index +)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find it's not grabbing three digits, but rather the sum of the six characters you are pulling out is a 3-digit number.

If you're after the largest five digit number, you need to extract five digits (not six) as you do *and* assign them a weight. So the first digit must be multiplied by 10,000, the second by 1,000 and so on.

But there's more: you're are getting the *character* at an index within your string. This is not what you want as it is not the same as the numeric value of that character. For that you need:

```
num.charAt(n) - '0'
```

These changes should allow you to correct your algorithm as it stands.

A more efficient approach would be to extract 5-digit sub-strings and convert them to integers. The first one would be:

```
Integer.parseInt(num.subString(0, 5));
```

You can iterate to get each one to find the greatest.

Comment: It's `substring`, and it's `(0, n]`. The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) says (in part) *The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.*